# Jumping tab order using Control.Focus() when pressing Tab key (.net 3.5)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, .net-3.5, focus

I have three text boxes:

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" LostFocus="textBox1_LostFocus" />
<TextBox Name="textBox2" />
<TextBox Name="textBox3" />
```

With this event:

```
private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Equals("some value"))
        textBox3.Focus();
}
```

When I press TAB key with focus on textBox1, the focus goes to textBox2, independently of textBox3.Focus().
How could I really set focus on textBox3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing I found that you are currently catching the wrong event. Changing the first line of your XAML code into the following

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" LostKeyboardFocus="textBox1_LostKeyboardFocus" />
```

and implementing the following method

```
private void textBox1_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e) {

    if (textBox1.Text.Equals("some value")) {
        Keyboard.Focus(textBox3);
    }
}
```

the focus in the window is correctly set to the desired control.